# How to redirect old Wordpress blog posts urls to new ones

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My Wordpress site's blog post URLs used to look like this:

`http://example.com/some-random-blog-post-name
http://example.com/other-random-blog-post-name
http://example.com/in-case-you-dont-get-the-point-theyre-all-different`

On my new Wordpress site I want them to live in a /blog/ subdirectory where they belong:

`http://example.com/blog/some-random-blog-post-name`

What's tricky about this is that the old URLs follow no pattern, so I think I need to match against anything unrecognized. Something like this almost works...

```
# Redirect unmatched blog posts to /blog/*
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !blog
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
```

...but it conflicts with Wordpress's own RewriteRules, and breaks all the other site pages that should pass through unchanged.

So how can I achieve the following:

`example.com/some-random-post` 301--> `example.com/blog/some-random-post`
`example.com/another-random-post` 301--> `example.com/blog/another-random-post`

`example.com/contact/` --> (No redirect)

Comment: What pattern of URLs should be redirected to `/blog` and what should not?

Comment: @anubhava I think it's already explained in the question above. There is no specific pattern to the old blog posts because they were not prefixed with a subdirectory. So basically we need to redirect anything that is not an existing Wordpress page.

Comment: In that case mod_rewrite is not the solution. It needs to be handled in WP itself.

Comment: @anubhava I'm all ears. What do you suggest

Comment: May be have a look at [RewriteMap](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap).

Comment: _“in a /blog/ subdirectory where they belong”_ – are you managing the rest of the site – outside that `/blog/` directory – with WordPress as well? If not, you could just install WP into an actual physical folder of that name. Plugins such as [Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) can help updating database content, rewriting all contained URLs as necessary (change domain, add a fixed path prefix.)

Comment: @CBroe The entire site is powered by WP, including the other static pages.

Comment: Or, since (/if?) basically all you’re doing is switching from the permalink structure `/post-name` to `/blog/post-name`, you could do that just via settings (https://codex.wordpress.org/images/c/c5/options-permalinks.png) – switch to Custom Structure, and insert the fixed path `/blog/` (no % placeholders) after the WP installation base path. (You might still have to update URLs contained inside database content, so in combination with aforementioned plugin that could work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `404.php` (or 404 handler) of your theme you can use this snippet at start of the file:

```
<?php

$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (stripos($url, "/blog/", 0) !== 0) {
   header("Location: " . "/blog" . $url);
   exit;
}

// rest of the 404 code
?>
```

Comment: Yea this is what I was thinking about too... I know it will work to stick the code in the 404.php template file, but I think ti would be cleaner if that logic lived in functions.php... Do you know is there a hook/filter for 404 requests?

Comment: I'm not WP expert actually. There is a function called `is_404()` that lets you use this 404 handling in `header.php` or `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would create a new file 'blog" on my ftp and I would cut and paste all the old wordpress in this new file. This way, you don't need to change anything in .htaccess, redirection will be automatically done in wordpress bo.

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're suggesting. Can elaborate on what is supposed to happen as a result of this?